# How to detect if a user had javascript disabled?

Tags: javascript, detect, browser-detection

I was talking with a friend about users who do not have javascript enabled in their browser and what could be done to show them a "no-javascript" version of your website.

Is it possible and how can it be done?

Thoughts?

Comment: @BalusC: Probably you're right, but how did you conclude that the single occurring JavaScript in the title was more important that the twice occurring Java in the body?

Comment: I think @BalusC is working on this badge :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30965/can-we-have-a-mind-reading-badge

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't try to build separate JS and non-JS versions of the site. Build a non-JS version and then [enhance it with JS](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build). This makes it easier to reuse code, allows you to use [object/feature detection](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html) for the *entire* stack, and makes it less likely that users without JavaScript will be left behind if developers update one branch of the site but not the other.

Comment: No disrespect, but the "enhancements" you're talking about are going to be of a disappointingly low order. Either that or you are just going to aim low from the start. Otherwise, you're *still* going to wind up with what is essentially two different versions of the site, both of which will have to be maintained.

Comment: With respect to Robusto, It's not really 2 versions of the site.  It's a working site, *always*, but with extra *features* for javascript users.   Mr. Dorward's advice is spot-on and jibes with years of hard-earned usability data.   It makes the site more fault tolerant and, in my experience, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean javascript, look up the `<noscript>` HTML tag.

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about JavaScript and want an alternate version of your site for those without, simply give them site without and put this at the top of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     location.replace('http:javascript-version-of-your-site');
</script>
```

Comment: The reverse is better - you can avoid the redirect by having the more common scenario be the default. see my comment below.

Comment: The meta refresh option is also a good idea, but may not be as search engine friendly, and may cause problems with the browser's "back" button, and some browsers that let you disable JS still ignore `noscript` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<noscript>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://foo/noscript.htm" />
</noscript>
</head>
<body>
...
```

The meta refresh (declarative redirect) only gets executed if there is no script enabled on the browser. Of course, the noscript tag is only understood by browsers that have a javascript engine. If you're trying to catch browsers that have NO javascript at all (I don't know of many) then this won't work.

Comment: Some browsers with JS engines will ignore the `noscript` tag, but then not execute any JS when it's disabled, leaving the page nonfunctional.

Comment: The noscript element is not allowed as a child of the head element, and meta elements may not be children of the noscript element. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1

Comment: Oh, the w3 recommendations. Recommendations, not rules. If HTML was strictly enforced, the world wide web would be a good deal smaller.

Answer (score 1):

I use this combination of JavaScript and CSS

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
    .js-on
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .js-off
    {
        background: red;
        color: White;
    }
 </style>
 <div id='jsdetect' class='js-off'><b>Javascript is OFF</b></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('jsdetect').className = 'js-on';
 </script>

</html>
```

It's useful if your only aim is to tell the users that Javascript is not available and that the site will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can put some code to log/track/alert you about users who have JavaScript disabled by using the  tag.

```
<noscript>
   // Do Something
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option open to you rather than the obvious noscript tag is to use JavaScript to drop a cookie, and then test for that cookie and deliver content appropriately. javascript ver vs non redirect or span

just thought I'd throw that in there..