# Can an .htaccess detect if the browser has a javascript enable or disable?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Can an htaccess could detect a browser if it's javascript enable or disabled and write a certain condition if javascript is disbled?

Like this

if(js)

DirectoryIndex ../locnfo/jsenable.php
else

DirectoryIndex ../locnfo/jsdisable.php

Comment: why you tagged this question with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to be done on the client side, it cannot be detected elsewhere. The best thing I would suggest is to have something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js"></script>');
</script>
```

so the file is only included if Javascript is enabled.

Answer (score 2):

No, an `.htaccess` file cannot do such a thing : an `.htaccess` file configures how Apache *(server)* behaves -- while Javascript is something that's on the client-side *(browser)*.

If you want to detect whether Javascript is enabled or not, you'll have to do that on the client-side.

About that, here are a couple of questions / answers that might help :

- [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)
- [How to detect if a user had javascript disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940662/how-to-detect-if-a-user-had-javascript-disabled)